# CSS issue with border on box-sizing missing the right side

Tags: css, border

I am applying the following CSS to a div in a page that is used for a horizontal menu the selected div is missing it's right border.
Also, selecting the div changes the size so it jumps to a new line so maybe there is a way of making it *inside* the div

```
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
border: dashed $color-button-passive; 1px;
```

However for some reason I just can not find, this is coming out like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avdzg.png)

Please can someone help me? I think the 1px is extending to the next div

Comment: maybe the div that is located on the right hide the right border of your div in question

Comment: The code you have given us isn’t enough to demonstrate the problem. I suspect we need to see the relevant HTML structure and related CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OK, here we go, please choose a Group first like "PooleVille" and then press the "Join us / renewals" button
Here we are: https://aqmrgdtevbjxsky-pprdb.adb.uk-london-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/r/u3a_dev/cloudu3a/